# Why in this example there is "for(auto& x : v)" and not "for(auto x : &v)"?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

**I found this code in Bjarne Stroustrup's The C++ programming language (4. edition).**

In this example, as far as my understanding goes, we increment x without copying the value of v into x. My question is, that *why do we reference to x, and not to v?*

I tried understanding the problem by breaking it down and writing it down onto a paper, that what would happen in the memory simplified, but I do not get it.

```
void increment()
{
   int v[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

   for(auto& x : v)
      {
        ++x;
      }
}
```

Comment: `auto& x` declares `x` as a reference to something, and in the context of looping over an array of `int` (what `v` is) then we have the compiler deduce that `x` is a reference to `int`. You would get the same result if you wrote `for (int& x : v)`.

Comment: I think you need to read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for carefully. It should help ;)

Comment: `for (auto &x : v)`  means that, on each loop iteration, `x` is a reference to an element of `v`.    `for (auto x : &v)` would means that `x` is the value of an element of `&v`, which is meaningless since `&v` is the address of `v` and is not a container (i.e. it does not represent a range of elements).

Comment: Also remember that like many other operators, the `&` could mean different things depending on context. In the context of e.g. `auto& x` (or `int& x`) then it's for declaring a variable that is a reference. In the context of `&v` then that's the address-of operator to create a pointer to `v` (of the type `int (*)[10]`), which hardly seems to be what's expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good beginner question. Have a look at what cppreference has on [range-based for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). Because `v` is an array type, this above snippet expands to

```
{
    auto && __range = v;

    for (auto __begin = __range, __end = (__range + bound);
        __begin != __end; ++__begin)
    {
        auto& x = *__begin;
        ++x
    }
}
```

where "`bound` is the number of elements in the array (if the array has unknown size or is of an incomplete type, the program is ill-formed)" [citation from the above link].

We can see, that the machinery behind such a range-based for loop makes sure that we act on an lvalue reference to `v` here: `auto && __range = v` uses type deduction with a forwarding reference, which does the right thing.

In short, with the `auto& x` part in the loop, you control what is being initialized when the iterators pointing into the range are dereferenced (`*__begin`). For example, with `auto& x` you get a reference to an element in the range (which you can change, affecting the range), with `const auto& x`, you get a `const`-qualified reference to an element in the range (which you can't mutate). You obtain copies of each element with `auto x`, and `const`-qualified copies of each element with `const auto x`, but the latter is hardly useful.

Answer (score 4):

Because the `for` loop is changing the array elements, so you want a reference to each element in order to increment them.

If you incorrectly had:

```
for(auto x : v)
{
    ++x;
}
```

nothing in `v` would change because `x` is a *copy* of the array elements.

Making it:

```
for(auto x : &v)
{
    ++x;
}
```

doesn't compile because `&v` is the address of *the array* (not the address of *the first element in the array* as `v` is) and is invalid in range expressions.

But using:

```
for(auto& x : v)
{
    ++x;
}
```

now makes `x` a *reference* to elements in `v` and can therefore change them.

Comment: _"only that your referring to `v` through a reference"_. By address not reference.

Comment: @Fareanor Correct - saw an ampersand and incorrectly saw a reference!  Answer corrected.

Comment: Taking the address of V, doesn't that cause a compilation error?

Comment: @JVApen Correct - thought this was tested but obviously not.  Compilation fails with: invalid range expression.  Answer corrected.